# Add filter (smooth line) in Time Series

Tags: r, ggplot2, filter, time-series

I created this time series. As you can see its a bit chaotic.

[image]

I used this code:

```
Stations$Code
Data[,1] = as.Date(Data[,1],format="%Y-%m-%d")
class(Data$Date)

ggplot(Data, aes(x = Date)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = AT31204), colour="yellow") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = ES1498A), colour = "orange") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = FR15044), colour = "red") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = FR09003), colour = "purple") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = ES1358A), colour = "blue") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = DEBW076), colour = "green") + 
  geom_line(aes(y = FR15044), colour = "brown") + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend) +
  ylab(label="Ozon µg/m3") + 
  xlab("Time")
```

How can I create smoother lines (one line is for one Station)? I thought about just taking the mean of the months, but is there any other way to do that automatically in the plot?

Comment: `geom_smooth` ?

Comment: I think I already tried that, but was unsure where to add it. Can you make an example maybe, where and how to use it in my case?

Comment: I believe you first want to tidy your data into long format (e.g. `gather`), then have one `geom_line(..., colour = GROUPS) + geom_smooth()`

Comment: Why would it be good to get my data into a long format?

Comment: just try to put `geom_smooth` instead of `geom_line`, we need a reproducible example to do more

Comment: Oh Thank you!! That already helped a lot! Its looks much better!